# CVS repository commit after copying

Tags: cvs

We've moved CVS repo to another host by simple 'cp', after that our programmer made changes to this copy. Now I'm trying to do `cvs commit`, but there is an error:

> cvs [commit aborted]: there is no version here; do `cvs checkout' first

How to make the commit in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you "cp" the repository, you have to re-init the cvs repository, that is made by the following steps:

First delete your CVSROOT:

```
$rm -rf /path/to/your/repository/CVSROOT
```

Then you have to re-init your repo:

```
$cvs -d /path/to/your/repo init
```

Then checkout the file you're working:

```
$cvs -d /path/to/your/repo checkout yourModule
```

Make the changes that you want to do it, and then you can properly commit:

```
~$cvs -d /path/to/your/repo commit yourModule
```

Hope it helps.